# Lost font when i move JS to an external sheet

Tags: javascript, html, css

I had some basic JS code for controlling my nav menus. When the code was inside  tags, in the HTML documents everything worked fine. When i moved the code to an external .js file i lost web font i applied to the sections in CSS. However i retained all other style aspects.

The font was completely removed from all elements on my webpages and i cant work out why, when i moved the JS back internally to the HTML file, the font returned. Having the JS externally isnt a must, but its something i have a preference for.

Comment: Hi Charlie, can you please post the HTML and the JS code so we can see if there is anything missing

Comment: Could you post some of your code? Where do you define the fonts that are lost? Where in the HTML do you write the JS (before removing) versus where you import the script in the HTML (after removing)?

Comment: can you show us the code to link to external file?

Comment: it looks like your font files path need to update. but we can answer you with more accuracy once we see you code

Comment: We need to see your code, please use this link and past your code inside and save: https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. 

I since tried recoding the entire <head>. This seemed to fix the issue. Upon further inspection the font link had changed. I must have misclicked into the webfont <link> and hit the backspace button while adding the <script>. It only removed 2 letters from the link, keeping it hyperlinked and appearing the same. This would be why my proof reads turned up with nothing. 

As for when i moved the JS back, i simply ctrl+z (undo), which explains why it worked when i had the JS internally. 

Sorry for wasting everyones time.